# Redmine Wiki (Texttile) Bullet points in Table cell

Tags: textmate, wiki, redmine

Is there any way to write a bullet pointed list within a cell in a Texttile formatted Redmine Wiki

The basic table syntax is

```
| Col 1R1 | Col 2R1 |
| Col 1R2 | Col 2R2 |
```

Bullet syntax is

```
* Bullet 1
* Bullet 2
```

I would think it would be written like

```
| Col 1R1
* Bullet 1
* Bullet 2
| Col 2R1 |
| Col 1R2 | Col 2R2 |
```

It almost works:

[image]

---

Alternatively, perhaps a way to nest tables in texttile?